# Label for the subcaption containing square brackets isn't acting nicely in the figure caption

Tags: graphics, hyperref, cross-referencing, subcaption, brackets

I often have to use "[" and "]" in various labels when cross-referencing items with formulas of inorganic complexes. Everything worked fine until I noticed a problem with `\subref{...}` of the `subcaption` package.

When used in the main caption, any entry with a label including square bracket(s) isn't referred correctly and no letter is assigned to the subfigure. Braces and curly brackets in the labels don't cause any issues:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{hyperref}
    \hypersetup{colorlinks = true}

\begin{document}

Check out Figure~\ref{fig:as[many]square[brackets]as[i]want[and]still[works]fine}. Subfigures~\ref{fig:foo{bar}-a} and \ref{fig:foo(bar)-b} are referenced properly in the main caption, whereas \ref{fig:foo[bar]-c} isn't.

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:foo{bar}-a}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:foo(bar)-b}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:foo[bar]-c}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{
        \subref{fig:foo{bar}-a} -- OK;
        \subref{fig:foo(bar)-b} -- OK;
        \subref{fig:foo[bar]-c} -- WTF?
    }
    \label{fig:as[many]square[brackets]as[i]want[and]still[works]fine}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I cannot just replace or stop using square brackets in the labels. How can I make the `\subref{...}` handle them properly?

As [nidhin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/28557/nidhin) pointed out in the comments, this most likely has to do with `hyperref` package. Disabling it actually brings back expected functionality. Unfortunately, I need `hyperref` too.

Comment: I think `hyperref` is the culprit

Comment: @nidhin Yep, you are right. I disabled `hyperref` and it all works fine now. However, `hyperref` became an essential package for me and I cannot get rid of it either:(

Comment: Is `\subref*` okay for you? But `c` in caption won't be a link in that case.

Comment: @nidhin Not that I particularly like it, but this definitely can be a workaround. Feel free to post an answer, and if you aware of the mechanism behind this `hyperref`'s behavior, I would really like to know it too:)

Comment: See the updated answer.

Comment: @nidhin It also would be interesting to deduce why `hyperref` doesn't treat the content of the square brackets as an argument outside `subfigure` though.

Comment: Hm.. `\ref` works fine.. That also has to be understood.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a stupid bug in `subcaption`, I simply forgot to put curly braces around the argument when passing it as optional argument to `\hyperref`. It's my fault; the `hyperref` package is fine here.

I will fix it within the next days (and upload a new version to CTAN), until then the following bugfix could be used after loading the `subcaption` package:

```
\makeatletter
% fix usage of [] within \subref{...}
\renewcommand*\@subref[2]{%
  \caption@ifundefined\hyperref
    {\subcaption@ref{#1}{#2}}%
    {\hyperref[{#2}]{\subcaption@ref{*#1}{#2}}}}
\makeatother
```

https://gitlab.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/issues/40

Answer (score 1):

#### Updated Answer

The issue is caused by `hyperref`. When `\subref` expands, the label is passed as an optional argument (inside square brackets) to `hyperref` command. Something like this:

```
\hyperref[fig:foo[bar]-c]{
...
}
```

Since there is a `]` in the label, the optional argument is terminated at that point. Hence the remaining `-c]` is printed before printing the actual subcaption.

Wrapping the closing square bracket in label inside braces can solve the issue. Change the label to:

```
\label{fig:foo[bar{]}-c}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks = true}

\begin{document}

Check out Figure~\ref{fig:as[many]square[brackets]as[i]want[and]still[works]fine}. Subfigures~\ref{fig:foo{bar}-a} and \ref{fig:foo(bar)-b} are referenced properly in the main caption, whereas \ref{fig:foo[bar{]}-c} isn't.

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:foo{bar}-a}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:foo(bar)-b}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:foo[bar{]}-c}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{
        \subref{fig:foo{bar}-a} -- OK;
        \subref{fig:foo(bar)-b} -- OK;
        \subref{fig:foo[bar{]}-c} -- WTF?
    }
    \label{fig:as[many]square[brackets]as[i]want[and]still[works]fine}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Another work around is to use `\subref*` instead of `\subref`. But it won't create link as shown in figure below.

[image]