# Subfigures with combined caption?

Tags: graphics, floats, subfloats

Is it possible to group figures into a single float and reference them separately, *without* creating separate caption for each of the figures?

[image]

I am aware of `subfloat` and `subfigure` environments, but they create separate captions for each figure. The feature I am specifically looking for is to have subfigure numbering (such as (a), (b), ...) but also have the captions grouped together into a single block of text, separated by references ((a), (b), ...) to the images.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a solution with `subcaption`. I think similar result can be obtained by using `subfloat` also.

Just give `\caption{}` without any arguments so that it will print only the *label* (*(a),(b)...*) not the *caption text*. And then caption can be given for main figure, where subfigures can be 'sub'-reffered. Sample output:

[image]

Corresponding MWE made by modifying code from [another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/463552/28557).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup{subrefformat=parens}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:a}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:b}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:c}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{
        \subref{fig:a} first figure.
        \subref{fig:b} second figure.
        \subref{fig:c} third figure.
    }
    \label{fig:main}
\end{figure}
Figure~\ref{fig:main} has three Subfigures--- \ref{fig:a}, \ref{fig:b} and  \ref{fig:c}.
\end{document}
```

#### EDIT

The caption can be placed on the left side by manually putting it there and using `\phantomsubcaption` to suppress the automatic caption. Sample output:

[image]

The corresponding code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup{subrefformat=parens}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
        {(a)~\includegraphics[width=0.25\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \phantomsubcaption\label{fig:a}}
        {(b)~\includegraphics[width=0.25\linewidth]{example-image-b}
        \phantomsubcaption\label{fig:b}}
        {(c)~\includegraphics[width=0.25\linewidth]{example-image-c}
        \phantomsubcaption\label{fig:c}}
    \caption{
        \subref{fig:a} first figure.
        \subref{fig:b} second figure.
        \subref{fig:c} third figure.
    }
    \label{fig:main}
\end{figure}
Figure~\ref{fig:main} has three Subfigures--- \ref{fig:a}, \ref{fig:b} and  \ref{fig:c}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: By any chance, do you know a method to get the label to the left of the images? I generally prefer to have output that looks as if I had written `(a)\includegraphics{...} (b)\includegraphics`.

Comment: @kdb See the edit made to answer.

Answer (score 1):

As alternative to [nidhin's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/464548/34769), one can also use the subfig package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  % [] Needed for the caption label (a), (b) to be typeset.
  \subfloat[\label{fig:mytopic-blabla}]{
    \includegraphics[height=5cm]{images/graph-mytopic-blabla.png}
  }
  \subfloat[]{
    % Label can be either in caption or body.
    \label{fig:mytopic-yadayada}
    \includegraphics[height=5cm]{images/graph-mytopic-yadayada.png}
  }
  \caption{
    % Must \protect the subref command inside floats/captions.
    \protect\subref{fig:mytopic-blabla}
    Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. 
    \protect\subref{fig:mytopic-yadayada}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
  }
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```